# Protractor & selenium server - how to download file in chrome and check if it was downloaded

Tags: download, protractor, selenium-server

I want to run tests using protractor via selenium server on another machine with diff ip address. For that I'm using seleniumAddress url. The problem which I see is how to check that after click on "Download" button in chrome browser file was downloaded, for now it won't work although if do that without selenium server it's working fine using

```
prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'default_directory': './tmp'
            }
        }
```